# Android button from transparent PNG. Make it blue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am using transparent PNGs to create buttons in an Android app. 
The images are white (where they are not transparent) and I would like to make them blue.

They are located in res/drawable and I use them in the XML like this:

```
<Button
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_facebook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How can I make this blue?

Comment: Could you show an example of one of those images?

Comment: its not programing Question you can create blue PNG as you have white and transparent PNG :)

Comment: its simple create button with blue background `PNGs` set button background with that drawable.

Comment: This is an example of an image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Tww.png

Comment: Yes I could change the color in GIMP but I would prefer to change the color in the XML file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can easly do it programatically using a [ColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html).

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_facebook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

first ad an id to your view like i did above, and after calling [setContentView(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) to your activity add the [ColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) like this:

```
Button button = root.findViewById( R.id.button);
Drawable drawable = button.getBackground();
drawable.setColorFilter( Color.BLUE, Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

Comment: This works like a charm! It would be nicer to do it via XML but this definitely does the job.

Comment: if this was the answer you were looking for, can you please accept the answer?